# Padding-bottom does not apply for divs

Tags: css, reactjs

I'd like to move up the stack list a little but it moves only when I apply padding-bottom to the main-container class, which moves the image as well. I want to fix the location of the image and move only the stack list. I'm calling a ProjectBox component from ProjectMain. How should I do that?

ProjectMain.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ProjectBox from "./ProjectBox";

export class ProjectMain extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="project-main-box">
        <div className="project-header">
          <div className="header-wrapper">
            <div className="project-bullet"></div>
            <div className="project-name">Projects</div>
            <h4>You can see the websites if you click them</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ProjectBox />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProjectMain;
```

ProjectBox.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TestImg from "../../test.jpg";

export class ProjectBox extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-container">
        <div className="proj-description">
          <div className="description-header">
            <h4>CoronaTrace</h4>
          </div>
          <p>
            A website that shows current covid19 cases over the states in the US
            with graphs and a table.
          </p>
          <div className="stacks">
            <h6>Stacks Used: </h6>
            <ul>
              <li>ReactJS</li>
              <li>Bootstrap</li>
              <li>Express</li>
              <li>MongoDB Atlas</li>
              <li>Recharts</li>
              <li>Heroku</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="img-container">
          <a
            href="https://www.google.com"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <img
              src={TestImg}
              height="100%"
              width="100%"
              alt="Img Not Found"
            ></img>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProjectBox;
```

App.scss

```
@mixin project-box {
  background-color: white;
  height: 400px;
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px #b0abaa;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px #b0abaa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px #b0abaa;
}

/* Projects Style */
.project-main-box {
  background-color: #ede7dd;
  height: 100%;

  // project header style
  .project-header {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;

    .header-wrapper {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 70px 0 50px 0;
      .project-bullet {
        @include bullet;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
      }
      .project-name {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    }
  }

  // ProjectBox Component Style
  .main-container {
    @include project-box;
    margin-bottom: 80px;

    .proj-description {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 55%;

      .description-header {
        background: blue;
        width: 10px;
        height: 50px;

        h4 {
          margin-left: 35px;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: blue;
        }
      }

      p {
        margin: 40px 30px;
      }

      .stacks {
        margin: 0 30px;
      }
    }

    .img-container {
      width: 45%;
      height: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  }
}
```

It's what it looks like now.
[image]

Comment: did you try `margin-bottom`?

Comment: Yeah I did but nothing changed.

Comment: Nvm, I fixed it.